# HTML mouse pointer region (chrome issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my CSS file, I made my mouse to change to hand-shape, when hover over progress-bar, by adding the "curser:pointer" to the style:

```
 .progressBar { 
   border:1px solid #aaa; 
   color:#fff; 
   width:295px; 
   height:5px;
   display:inline-block;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.progress {
   background-color:#ff0000; 
   height:5px;
   display:inline-block;
   width: 100%; 
}
```

(note that my progress color is "red".)
It works fine, and in fact my progress-bar is clickable, and I have a JS code that does the clicking action. Things works fine. But for some reason the hand-shape has a higher height on the "red" region !?!

See, in snapshot #2, once I move the mouse slightly under the bar, the hand-shape disappears, but in snapshot #4 (in the "red" region), the hand-shape doesn't disappear til I move the mouse even further down !

[image]

I just realized that I only encounter this when I am using Chrome, since when I loaded my page with IE, I didn't see that problem ?!?

Here is my code to click on the bar:

```
   $('#progressBar2').bind('click', function (ev) {
    var $div = $(ev.target);
    var offset = $div.offset();
    var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
    audioElement2.currentTime = x;
    });
```

And, here is the code to update the progress bar:

```
function updateProgress2() {
   var progress = document.getElementById("progress2");
   var value = 0;
   if (audioElement2.currentTime > 0) {
      value = Math.floor((100 / audioElement2.duration) * audioElement2.currentTime);
   }
   progress.style.width = value + "%";

   var currResult = document.getElementById("currTime2");
   currResult.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(audioElement2.currentTime);
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Comment: I am assuming it is because there is some element overflow there. Hard to tell with no demo. You should right click in frame 4 and then inspect element and see what comes up.

Comment: Show representative code to reproduce the problem, also consider posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo.

Comment: Inform your html code also.